# Wait for stdout stream to finish and then add its contents to a file

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I am trying to run a command in bash where I have a `command 1` which accepts a large amount content through stdin and then outputs that content to a `file.txt`, however, `command 1` generates a stream of content and apparently `file.txt` gets created as soon as `command 1` starts and then gets updated once `command 1` finishes with the correct output.

```
echo 'a lot of content' | command 1 > file.txt
```

The problem is that I only want to create or touch `file.txt` once `command 1` is completely finished.

Is there any way to achieve that?

### Edit:

Use-case: I am using a web development server that gets refreshed every time a file changes, so I am doing some pre-processing before really updating the file.

The problem with the above command is that if the file is updated or create with empty content the server refreshes instantly, having an empty page, so I really wanted to wait for the post processing to finish (let's say it takes about 4 seconds) and only then touch `file.txt` so it is correctly rendered on the page.

So there's only one command I need to run here, which is `command 1` and then, after `file.txt` is updated, my web development server will refresh automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably `sponge` as [@heemayl suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274000/22222). Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
command > tmpfile && mv tmpfile watched_file
```

This will cause `command` to save its output in `tmpfile`, which will only be renamed to `watched_file` (the file your server is set up to watch) once the command has exited and only if it has exited successfully. To also rename it on failure, use:

```
command > tmpfile; mv tmpfile watched_file
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the `tmpfile` method since I was looking for something that could work without dependencies.

Comment: If the `command` fail, an unused `tmpfile` will be created. To prevent that we can do something like this `{ command >tmpfile && mv tmpfile watched_file; } || rm tmpfile`

Answer (score 16):

Use `sponge` from GNU `moreutils`:

```
echo 'a lot of content' | command 1 | sponge file.txt
```

Or use a temporary file.